# Firebase functions deploy failed for @ng-toolkit/universal

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-universal

I am building angular 7 app and using angular universal for server side rendering, everything works fine on local but when I try to deploy the application on firebase, then firebase function logs show the following error -

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Build failed: exit status 254\nnpm ERR! addLocal Could not install /workspace/node_modules/@ng-toolkit/universal/@ng-toolkit/_utils@1.1.50\nnpm WARN deprecated bugsnag@2.4.3: All projects should upgrade to our universal JS notifier: \"@bugsnag/js\". See https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-js/blob/master/UPGRADING.md for more details.\nnpm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-1026-gcp\nnpm ERR! argv \"/nodejs/bin/node\" \"/nodejs/bin/npm\" \"--global-style\" \"--production\" \"--fetch-retries=5\" \"--fetch-retry-factor=2\" \"--fetch-retry-mintimeout=1000\" \"install\" \"/workspace\"\nnpm ERR! node v6.14.0\nnpm ERR! npm  v3.10.10\nnpm ERR! path /workspace/node_modules/@ng-toolkit/universal/@ng-toolkit/_utils@1.1.50\nnpm ERR! code ENOENT\nnpm ERR! errno -2\nnpm ERR! syscall open\n\nnpm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/@ng-toolkit/universal/@ng-toolkit/_utils@1.1.50'\nnpm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/@ng-toolkit/universal/@ng-toolkit/_utils@1.1.50'\nnpm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself\nnpm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.\nnpm ERR! enoent \n\nnpm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:\nnpm ERR!     /workspace/npm-debug.log\n"},"authenticationInfo":.....
```

Settings in functions/package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.50",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "~7.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "~7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootswatch": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "~2.8.4",
    "firebase": "^5.7.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26",
    "@nguniversal/common": "~7.0.0",
    "express": "~4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Just a quick note: Serverless functions currently have a "cold boot" time that can be seconds. Therefore serverless is IMHO not the best solution for Angular Universal if the goal is performance. Be prepared to have loading times of 600 ms and way worse for "cold" boot.

Comment: @CanK.  - Yes I agree with you, I honestly did not think it like that, please make some suggestions for this. What can I use and what not?
I use universal mainly for SEO and not the performance as it help in generating the content that search engines can see.

Comment: If your site is not dynamic, you can pre-render it with universal e.g. every 24 h or every month and serve the HTML as static files. Or you use Serverless and add something like CloudFlare to it. That will be fast too. In general, we have multiple sites running with Angular, some with Universal some without. Google can render all of them without any issue. Only other search engines have problems. The simplest and best result is probably to use Serverless with CDN like CloudFlare infront. You will experience perfect performance and the site is pre-rendered.

Comment: Thank for the suggestions, my site is not dynamic and hence I think I should go for the static one as of now.

Answer (score 0):

The issues looks to be with the ng-toolkit/universal dependency. The dependency is a cli that helps you setup a boilerplate project and from their github page (https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit#readme) I see that the dependency should be globally installed and not shipped with the app itself. Move the dependency to a devDependency in package.json or just install it globally and remove it from package.json

Comment: I am new to all this, so I might be making silly mistakes, but if I understand you correctly I installed it globally and remove the dependency from functions package.json as well as from the main package.json but then it gives me new error.

`Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '@ng-toolkit/universal'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rendertron` to Server Side Rendering, It Does NOT require Angular Universal or any weird hacks. Just focus on developing your Angular Application.

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/seo-angular-part-1-rendertron-meta-tags/